# Getting a composite user control to handle KeyDown events

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForm application(calculator) that is importing a composite user control.  The user control has a keyDown event handler to link the keyboard to buttons on the control.  When launching my program, no keyDown events are recognized or performed.

After reading through some similar posts, I now think it has something to do with the focus not being on my control.  I tried doing a CalcCompCtrl1.focus() on my WinForm load to no avail.  How could I go about fixing this?

Why does creating a keyDown event handler in my Form.vb and simply passing the info along not work?

```
Private Sub Calc_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    CalcCompCtrl1.MyCalc_KeyDown(sender, e)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work, a UserControl is adamant at not taking the focus.  It will force it to one of the client controls if you try to use the sledge-hammer.  The KeyPreview hack cannot work either, it is a VB6 legacy property that UserControl does not have.

You must override [ProcessCmdKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.  Winforms calls it *before* it fires the KeyDown event on the control that has the focus.  Return *true* from the method if you used the keystroke, call base.ProcessCmdKey() if you didn't.  Be selective, you don't want to swallow everything or basic stuff like keyboard navigation (cursor keys and tabbing) will stop working.

Comment: After debugging I found my above code to work by simply sending the KeyDown event parameters to my control KeyDown function. (1 minute it didn't work, next minute it did??) Thanks for this information though as I expect I will need it very soon.

Answer (score 1):

Enable KeyPreview on the Form. It is a property.

Try to change the MyBase to the Variable-Name of the Calc-Object-Variable!

Comment: I set KeyPreview to true, but that did not solve the problem. I edited the code above. You meant after the handles like I changed above?  Seemed to have no affect.